# How to round off numbers in excel for given intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I making an excel spreadsheet with prices for work.
The prices need to end on: 12, 20, 40, 60, 80 or 00 (with NO decimals).
Which number they should end on can be seen in below interval table below that I have made:

```
12 if  15 > x ≥ 6
20 if  30 > x ≥ 15
40 if  50 > x ≥ 30 
60 if  70 > x ≥ 50 
80 if  90 > x ≥ 70 
00 if   9 > x ≥ 90
```

Examples:

```
x = 10669,56 should be converted to 10660,00
x = 922,56 should be converted to 920,00
x = 7448,73 should be converted to 7440,00
```

Does anyone have an idea as to which commands I would need to use and how to set it up?

Comment: This sounds very *iffy*!

Comment: How many prices have to be converted in one spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will do the trick:

```
=TRUNC(A1,-2)  +  XLOOKUP(TRUNC(A1,0)-TRUNC(A1,-2),$I$1:$I$7,$J$1:$J$7,,1)
```

Before starting to explain, I want to point out you have a conflict in the values to round to. At first, you have values down to 6 (so including 6, 7, and 8) rounding to 12, but at the end you want values below 9 (so including 6, 7, and 8) rounding to 00. My bet was you intended a "below 6" at the end and the rest of this assumes that. If <9 was correct, adjust the first entry in the lookup table that follows.

My original (deleted) answer kept getting changed with "Well, actually, there's an easier way to do that part so use this" and that got ridiculous after a bit. So here's the new, improved version of things.

You don't need (or want) to do any weird and complex actual rounding. So no worries about `ROUND()`, `MROUND()`, or `INTEGER()` and any of the oddities they bring with them. Nor the difficulties having strange rounding bands would bring.

You're going to take the input value, strip off the decimal part as it is not helpful in any way and is not desired in the final result. That will be done as an additional benefit of the fact that you are going to take apart the value and work with its parts.

First, you need the portion that is hundreds and higher. So for 10669, that means the 10600 part, dropping the final two digits off. That part is simple and never has anything done to it... it just waits around until the second part is figured out and gets added to it.

To do it, you use `TRUNC()` to truncate the value. The function's "Intellisense" help makes it seem like you enter how many digits from the original you want, but that's flat out wrong. You actually enter the number of decimal places you want kept. If you enter "0", you get an integer value that is just the original cut off at the decimal place. If you enter "2", you get two decimal places. If you enter "negative two:  -2", you get the tens and ones digits cut off. It's a little misleading in that. You could think that means truncating 10669 to -2 digits would give you "106" (cutting those last two digits off), but what it really does is cut those off BUT replace them with zeros. So you get the "10600" you desire here.

Alrighty. So that's done and waiting for the final two digits to add to it. For that you need a two column, seven row table with the first column the breakpoints in your rounding rules and the second column the results for each one. You can copy and paste this one:

| Lookup | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 00 |
| 15 | 12 |
| 30 | 20 |
| 50 | 40 |
| 70 | 60 |
| 90 | 80 |
| 99 | 00 |

You could also load it into a Named Range so it doesn't have to appear ON your sheet, in case you'd prefer that or in case there's no room for it. To do that, actually enter the table on some sheet, let's say the I1:J7 I used, and use the following function, one NO ONE seems to know about for whatever reason:

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(I1:J7,1)
```

Its output is:  `{6,0;15,12;30,20;50,40;70,60;90,80;99,0}` (after you copy and Paset|Special|Values) which you can copy and paste into the Named Range's "Refers to" box. EASIEST way to load a table into anything, Named Range or otherwise, as it takes care of the commas and semi-colons for you.

*(By the way, your questions makes it pretty clear you are not using an English version of Excel, or maybe more exactly, your Windows settings for things like decimal separators are different, so you will have to adjust anything I wrote to fit your situation.)*

So, back to the second half of the formula. You use the table for a lookup. The lookup value is the final two digits of the truncated number. The easy way to get those two digits is to subtract the "truncated to -2 places" value from the complete "truncated to 0 places" number. So 10669-10600 gives you 69. That is looked up using `XLOOKUP()` not because I don't love `VLOOKUP()` but because it does something `VLOOKUP()` (my old, old friend) cannot:  it lets you specify that you want an "Exact match or the next higher" which means that looking up "69" doesn't find an exact match, so it chooses the next higher value in the table, "70", and returns 60.

So now you have the two numbers the formula needs to add and it adds them giving you the apparently rounded result, but without ever "really" rounding.

*Remember `ARRAYTOTEXT()`. It is hugely easier for creating array strings than loads of typing, making sure all the commas and semi-colons are right, or standard string techniques for building out long arrays that follow some kind of pattern or actually literally do the hard way what it does in one step. It's just amazing how many SE questions one can find in which people use convoluted methods to do its work! It's almost as bad as how many people use nasty, horrible looking formulas to find a column letter name when just using `ADDRESS()` with "1" for the row and the column number for the column, then `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove the extra bits.*

Anyhow, that's it. No need for VBA. But if you know VBA, and are allowed to use it in your environment, it is always the gold standard for anything even halfway complicated.

Comment: Hi Jeorje
Thank you for taking your time to write the answer! I have applied it and it works perfectly - so thank you for this. I think I'll name my firstborn Trunc.

Yes I am from Denmark where we use , and . oppsite of English :-) 
The only small mistake I found was that in the Lookup table when Lookup is 99 the result should be 100 and not 0 to make the differences between actual number and rounded number minium. 

Again thank you for your help!!
Luca

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/1504610/jeorje and https://superuser.com/users/1517540/jeorje.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your answer.

Comment: P.S. If you plan on being a member of the Stack Exchange community, I suggest that you *register* your merged account.

Comment: Also, you misunderstood @luca ryberg Lonardi’s comment. They aren’t saying that ``I7`` should be 100 instead of 99; they’re saying that ***`J7`*** should be 100 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a user-defined [custom function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f):

```
Function PriceRound(price As Double) As Double
    Dim iPrice As Integer
    Dim m100 As Integer
    
    iPrice = CInt(price)
    m100 = iPrice Mod 100
    iPrice = iPrice - m100
    
    If m100 < 6 Then
        m100 = 0
    ElseIf m100 < 15 Then
        m100 = 12
    ElseIf m100 < 30 Then
        m100 = 20
    ElseIf m100 < 50 Then
        m100 = 40
    ElseIf m100 < 70 Then
        m100 = 60
    ElseIf m100 < 90 Then
        m100 = 80
    Else
        m100 = 100
    End If
        
    PriceRound = iPrice + m100
End Function
```

Without a custom function, you could use a nested [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function to go through all the cases. That was probably meant by *IFFY* in the comments.

To reduce the number of cases, you could first check, if the value belongs to the regular range rounded to a multiple of `20`. Otherwise, it is rounded to the end digits `12`.